# Javascript: Keep count of even and odd random numbers and get the sum of each

Tags: javascript

When I run this program I am only getting the even number count and the odd sum. The odd count and even sum just gives me 0 every time. 
Does anyone have any idea what I am missing? Thanks!

I am trying to generate 100 random numbers and keep count of the evens/odds and then get the sum of each.

```
var min = 1;
var max = 1000;
var randomNumArray = []
var oddCount = []
var evenCount = []
var oddSum = []
var evenSum = []

function isEven(x){
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function sumOfArray(evenSum){
    for(i = 0; i< evenSum.length; i++){
        if (isEven){
            return(evenSum);
        }
        else{
        return (oddSum);
        }
    }
}
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    var randNumber = Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * max));
    randomNumArray.push(randNumber);
}

for( i = 0; i< randNumber.length; i++){
    if (isEven(evenCount[i])){
        return evenCount;
    }
    else{
        return oddCount;
    }
}

console.log('Even Number Count: ' + evenCount);
console.log('Odd Number Count: ' + oddCount);
console.log('Sum Even: ' + evenSum);
console.log('Sum Odd: ' + oddSum);
```

Comment: Why is oddSum and evenSum an array? you are printing it but a) you have to print the lenght or b) change the type

Comment: are you missing some code?

Comment: You're never summing or counting anything at all anywhere in the code.

Comment: It would probably be best if you tested your code with some static dummy values, and only when you're confident it works introduce real random numbers. Currently this makes your code harder to debug.

Comment: "When I run this program I am only getting the even number count and the odd sum." I doubt you're even getting that.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use 1 function to check if its even or odd and then decide to add the sum by the number itself and the count by 1. You are making it way more complicated and I'm wondering why u are using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  var randNumber = Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * max));
  if(isEven(randNum)){
     evenSum = evensum+randNum;
     evenCount ++;
  }else{
     oddSum= oddSum+randNum;
     oddSum++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oddCount = 0
var evenCount = 0
for(i=0; i<randomNumArray.length; i++) {
    if(randomNumArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evenCount++
    } else {
        oddCount++
    }
};
```

Something like that should work?

Comment: Oh, for the love of God, don't upvote this answer - it's wrong!

Comment: Everyone remain calm!